# How does a Bash for loop read script parameters?

Tags: bash, for-loop, parameter-passing

Normally, script parameters are read from `$1`, `$2`, ...
Sometimes this is combined with `shift` and a `while`-loop and `case`-statement to process multiple parameters.

```
while [[ $# > 0 ]]; do
  case "$1" in
    -v|--verbose)
      VERBOSE=1
      ;;
    -d|--debug)
      VERBOSE=1
      DEBUG=1
      ;;
    *)      # unknown option
      echo 1>&2 -e "${COLORED_ERROR} Unknown command line option '$key'.${ANSI_NOCOLOR}"
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
  shift # parsed argument or value
done
```

Today, I found a code snippet based on a simple `for`-loop:

```
#! /bin/bash
for opt; do
  echo $opt
done
```

Execution:

```
$ ./test.sh foo bar spam
foo
bar
spam
```

Normally, one would see `for i in ...; do`.
Why/how can a simplified *for*-loop access script parameters?

Does it also work with parameters in functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `help for`:

> If `in WORDS ...;` is not present, then `in "$@"` is assumed.